# How to translate the ng-select dropdown values using ngx-translate in Angular 10?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I was having requirement to translate the dropdown values if user change different language.

I know one solution to use the pipe and transform async behavior but thinking if we have better solution than this.

below is code for solution.

```js
translate-options.pipe.ts

@Pipe({
  name: 'translateOptions',
})
export class TranslateOptionsPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }


  transform(items: any) {    
    const observable = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.translateService.get(items).subscribe(result => {            
            // result will be an object
            // e.g. { 'JOBS.UX': 'UX Designer', 'JOBS.DEVELOPER': 'Developer' }
            observer.next(result);
        });        

        this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(event => {
            this.translateService.get(items).subscribe(result => {            
                observer.next(result);
            });
        })
    });

    return observable;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.translateService.onLangChange.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```html
app.component.html

<ng-select
    [addTag]="true"
    [addTagText]="to.addTagText || 'Create item: '"
    [multiple]="to.multiple"
    [closeOnSelect]="!to.multiple"
    (change)="onAutoCompleteChange($event)"  
>
    <ng-option
        *ngFor="let item of items | translateOptions | async | keyvalue" 
        [value]="item.key"
    >
        {{ item.value }}
    </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add  [(items)] input API to the ng select and use custom template for options and Label

```
<ng-select
[(items)]="items"
[addTag]="true"
[addTagText]="to.addTagText || 'Create item: '"
[multiple]="to.multiple"
[closeOnSelect]="!to.multiple"
(change)="onAutoCompleteChange($event)"  
   >
<<ng-template ng-option-tmp  ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
      {{item | translate}} 
    </ng-template>  
</ng-select>
```